# Separating java and html

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am developing a web site with jsp.
Like in php, I am trying to separate html and java code to check user and calling html content by java classes.

Here is my index.jsp page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%=DefaultTagContents.putHeader()%>
  </head>
  <body>
      <%
          if(request.getSession().getAttribute("username") == null){
              out.print(DefaultTagContents.putUnRegisteredNavbar());
              out.print(DefaultTagContents.putUnregisteredIndexContent());
          }else{
              out.print(DefaultTagContents.putRegisteredNavbar());
              out.print(DefaultTagContents.putRegisteredIndexContent());
          }
      %>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I use classes like above; it becomes so confusing.Here is the java class "DefaultTagContents" :

```
public static String putRegisteredNavbar(){
    return "<nav class=\"navbar navbar-default\">\n" +
            "    <div id=\"content-container\" class=\"container-fluid\">\n" +
            "\n" +
            "        <ul class=\"nav navbar-nav\">\n" +
            "            <li><a href=\"index.jsp\">Ana Sayfa</a></li>\n" +
            "            <li><a href=\"profile.jsp\">Profilim Ne Halde?</a></li>\n" +
            "            <li><a href=\"about.jsp\">Siz Kimsiniz?</a></li>\n" +
            "        </ul>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "        <form class=\"navbar-form navbar-right\">\n" +
            "            <div class=\"input-group\">\n" +
            "                <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Ne istedin?\">\n" +
            "                <div class=\"input-group-btn\">\n" +
            "                    <div class=\"input-group-btn\">\n" +
            "                        <button class=\"btn btn-default\" type=\"submit\">\n" +
            "                            <i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-search\"></i>\n" +
            "                        </button>\n" +
            "                    </div>\n" +
            "                </div>\n" +
            "            </div>\n" +
            "        </form>\n" +
            "    </div>\n" +
            "</nav>";
}
```

This seems so complex to develop index page html.What should I do instead of using it like this?

Comment: What you do in `putRegisteredNavbar` is awful. Never do that, it is impossible to maintain and extremely hard to read. Keep in mind the MVC pattern. In Java EE applications, your model is composed of POJOs often associated to your database through an ORM like Hibernate. Servlets are controllers. JSPs are views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing it (and using `java scriptlets` in general) is definitely not recommended and should be avoided.

`JSP` pages are used as *views* in `MVC` pattern. They are meant for separating the concern of business logic from that of presentation.

In this case, you can put `html` code in separate files and *include* them according to the condition (whether username is set).

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>

<head>
    <%=DefaultTagContents.putHeader()%>
</head>

<body>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${sessionScope.username != null}">
            <jsp:include page="RegisteredNavbar.html" />
            <jsp:include page="RegisteredIndexContent.html" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <jsp:include page="UnRegisteredNavbar.html" />
            <jsp:include page="UnRegisteredIndexContent.html" />
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I wrote this yesterday by myself :) but thank you, this is the right answer that I was looking for.